# Creating an application from a Terminal comand

Tags: terminal, launching-application

How would I go about creating a short cut or other type of app that I can just click on with this command:

```
open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --ignore-certificate-errors
```

I'm fairly new to this.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using bash:

open ~/.bash_aliases with your favourite editor and define an alias as follows:

```
alias chrome_alias='open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --ignore-certificate-errors'
```

obviously you could modify the name of the alias